# db2 external function ends with SQL0444N, Reason code 6, SQLSTATE 42724

Tags: db2, db2-luw

I'll develop new (external) functions for DB2. My first test:

db2crypt.h

```
#ifndef DB2CRYPT_H
#define DB2CRYPT_H

#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *encryptAes(const char *source, const char *key);
#endif /* DB2CRYPT_H */
```

db2crypt.cpp

```
#include "db2crypt.h"

#include <string>

char *encryptAes(const char *source, const char *key) {
    std::string test("abc");
    return (char *)test.c_str();
}
```

is compiled without an error.

```
g++ -fPIC -c db2crypt.cpp  -std=c++14
g++ -shared -o db2crypt db2crypt.o -L$DB2PATH -ldb2
```

I also copied the new file into $DB2PATH/function and made a softlink in $DB2PATH/function/unfenced.

Then I created the function with

```
create function aes(VARCHAR(4096), VARCHAR(4096)) 
SPECIFIC encryptAes 
RETURNS VARCHAR(4069) 
NOT FENCED 
DETERMINISTIC 
NO SQL 
NO EXTERNAL ACTION 
LANGUAGE C 
RETURNS NULL ON NULL 
INPUT PARAMETER STYLE SQL 
EXTERNAL NAME "db2crypt!encryptAes"
```

which was also ok.

But when I do `select db2inst1.aes('a', 'b') from SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1`
I get the error

```
SQL0444N  Die Routine "DB2INST1.AES" (spezifischer Name "ENCRYPTAES") ist
durch Code in Bibliothek oder Pfad ".../sqllib/function/db2crypt", Funktion
"encryptAes" implementiert, auf die kein Zugriff möglich ist.  Ursachencode:
"6".  SQLSTATE=42724
```

(sorry, I don't know how to change the error output into english)

What I made wrong?

Comment: For SQL0444N, Reason code 6 means "The function "<function-code-id>" could not be found in the library that was named." Looks like the function source does not follow the IBM pattern in samples.  Suggest you get the IBM C++ and C sample functions working first on your environment. These are in the instance-owner home directory under sqllib/samples/cpp  and sqllib/samples/c.  They show in particular the use of the SQL_API_RC and SQL_API_FN defines that the function should use, and they show how to build them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I got the answer.
Thank you at @mao, you did help me. But I also needed some other help. If someone searches for an answer:

First you have to compile with some important parameters:

```
g++ -m64 -fPIC -c <yourfile>.cpp -std=c++14 -I/opt/ibm/db2/V11.1/include/ -D_REENTRANT
g++ -m64 -shared -o <yourfile> <yourfile>.o -L$DB2PATH -ldb2 -Wl,-rpath,$DB2PATH/$LIB -lpthread
```

Second: The function declaration, you also have to add parameters for null values AND the return value can't be a function return, it has to be a parameter. Also you have to use the types which are defined in sqludf.h:

```
void SQL_API_FN encryptAes(SQLUDF_CHAR      *source,
                        SQLUDF_CHAR      *key,
                        SQLUDF_CHAR      out[4096],
                        SQLUDF_SMALLINT  *sourcenull,
                        SQLUDF_SMALLINT  *keynull,
                        SQLUDF_SMALLINT  *outnull,
                        SQLUDF_TRAIL_ARGS) {
...
}
```

Also, when you do C++ instead of C, you have to tell the script that it has to handle the function as C:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
#endif
void SQL_API_FN ...
```